Ubuntu 24.04 Remote Login lags and freezes
I need assistance with Remote Login on Ubuntu 24.04.
Here’s my setup:
A MacBook with a 4K monitor, using Windows Remote Desktop.
A laptop running Ubuntu 24.04.
Both devices are on the same Wi-Fi network. I’ve enabled Remote Login on the Ubuntu laptop and am connecting to it from the MacBook via Windows Remote Desktop.
The problem is that when I set the resolution to 2K, 4K, or enable the "Optimize for Retina displays" option, I experience significant lag and freezes, making it difficult to work. However, when I switch to Full HD, the connection is smooth, but the resolution is too low for comfortable work.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
